# HERE Maps : No implementation found for GeoCoordinates in SDK navigate edition

Tags: android, gradle, here-api

recently we switched to HERE maps SDK navigate edition 4.14.2.0.11531 , everything went well but when using GeoCoordinates class , we get this crash :

`No implementation found for com.here.sdk.core.GeoCoordinates com.here.sdk.core.GeoCoordinates.make(double, double) (tried Java_com_here_sdk_core_GeoCoordinates_make and Java_com_here_sdk_core_GeoCoordinates_make__DD)`

..
i cnt reproduce the problem when i create a new project and implement hello map ;

i did try Clean project , rebuild , change SDK version but nothing really did work ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one reason for this error could be that your Here Maps SDK is not initialized at this point of time. In that case consider doing something like this:

```
public static void initializeHERESDK(Context context) {
  // Set your credentials for the HERE SDK
  String accessKeyID = "...."; 
  String accessKeySecret = "..."; 
  SDKOptions options = new SDKOptions(accessKeyID, accessKeySecret);
  try {
    SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(context, options);
  } catch (InstantiationErrorException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Initialization of HERE SDK failed: " + e.error.name());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize GeoCoordinates members before the HERE SDK is  initialized.

For example:

```
MyClass {
   GeoCoordinates myCoord = new GeoCoordinates(0,0); // This will crash at runtime.
}
```

Instead, you need to rewrite like this:

```
MyClass {
   GeoCoordinates myCoord;

   MyClass() {
      // 1. Init HERE SDK
      // 2. init member:
      myCoord = new GeoCoordinates(0,0);    
   }
}
```